# Visual Studio Color Selected Object

Tags: visual-studio-2010, color-scheme

I am trying to modify the sons of obsidian theme so that the selected object does not have a white background with white text as in the screen shot below. I cannot figure out which style this is, and have tried changing every white background object in the list without success.

I have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 w/ Resharper 6 & VScommands installed.

[image]

Any idea which Visual Studio Style this is?

Answer (score 0):

Under `Text Editor` that is the `Highlighted Reference` entry. You can change both the background and the foreground. But the later is actually used as an outline and does not color the text.